# Why did they pick Lacrosse and not football?

Tags: production, teen-wolf-tv

The *Teen Wolf* TV show is loosely based on the film of same name where  basketball was the essential part of the plot but in the TV show they changed it to lacrosse.

But why? Games like basketball and football have better global approach. Lacrosse doesn't seem like a recognizable game outside of America. So why did they pick lacrosse?

Comment: Lacrosse is barely recognizable **in** the US... :/

Comment: @Catija In India I can bet nobody knows about it except who watch this show.

Comment: Lacrosse could also be something of an analogy to werewolves/wolves.

It is a team based sport (packs), however parts of it can be played independently (lone wolf), better players (alphas) rally teammates to make plays (werewolves forming packs) weaker players either join (betas) or are left out of a play (omegas). From [teenwolf wiki](http://teenwolf.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:122930)

Comment: @irsha same can be said for football or basketball or hockey?

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Basketball is not a contact sport. Football _generally_ relies on strength over agility. Hockey isn't a contact sport. Ice hockey is, but ice skating is not an innate werewolf skill. Lacrosse has the benefit here: a team sport, a contact sport, requires you to run around, and relies on agility more than brute strength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The show's writer and producer Jeff Davis explains](http://www.dreadcentral.com/news/24599/executive-producer-jeff-davis-talks-new-teen-wolf-series/):

> Davis said, “A lot of the conflict of the first season is Scott having
>   to control and hide his abilities now that he’s a werewolf. **One of the
>   reasons we actually chose lacrosse as the sport is that he gets to
>   wear a helmet and it’s a much more violent sport than basketball.** So
>   we get to hide his features under a mask, which can help, but he still
>   has to struggle to control his powers because it’s possible for him as
>   a werewolf to get so worked up on the field that he could almost kill
>   someone.”

He provides [a similar answer in this interview](https://thetvwatchtower.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/summer-scoop-a-few-candid-insights-from-writerproducer-jeff-davis-and-director-russell-mulcahy-on-mtvs-teen-wolf/):

> **One of the reasons we chose lacrosse as the sport is he gets to wear a
>   helmet — and it’s a much more violent sport than basketball** — although
>   I’ve seen some pretty impressive fights in basketball.  So we get to
>   hide his features under a mask and he gets to race across the screen
>   at night.  So we were able to take some liberties with that with the
>   sport — hiding him under a helmet.

[In another interview](https://www.assignmentx.com/2011/exclusive-interview-teen-wolf-producer-jeff-davis-transforms-the-1980s-film-into-mtv%E2%80%99s-new-horror-series-part-2/) he points to multiple reasons:

> **ASSIGNMENT X:** Lacrosse – really? I don’t know of any California high school team
>   that has lacrosse.
>
> **DAVIS:** **I grew up in Connecticut, and lacrosse was a very big sport at
>   our prep school.** We decided **a lot of other TV shows and movies have
>   done basketball and have done them probably better than I could do**.
>   And **I remember kids walking around high school with lacrosse sticks
>   sticking out of their backpacks and looking like gladiators. They
>   always looked pretty cool**. First of all, lacrosse has never been seen,
>   and second of all, it’s a pretty violent sport. It was developed by
>   native Americans as a way to resolve conflicts. They would play it for
>   weeks with hundreds of players and it would get quite bloody. It has
>   an interesting history and it adds a certain amount of violence and
>   energy to the series.